# How can use a custom folder asset using namespace routes?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

I'm trying to use a template created and apply it into a ruby on rails project without adding assets or use ruby on rails procedures.

Is it possible to use a custom folder on namespace routes?

When I execute the project doesn't works without using namespaces but when i use a resources it works perfect.

Examples:

```
user_management/users/index.html.erb works ok.
user_management/users/new.html.erb  doesn't load assets.
user_management/users/new.html.erb  doesn't load assets.
users/index.html.erb works ok.
users/ new.html.erb works ok.
users/edit.html.erb works ok.
```

Github project code:

```
 https://github.com/sayayingod/app_sow
```

application.rb

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/color_admin_v4.5/assets/").each do |path|
      config.assets.paths << path
end
```

Routes.rb

```
namespace :user_management do
  resources :users
end    

resources :users 
#Root Configuration
root 'user_management/users#new'
```

user_management/users/new.html

[image]

users/new.html.erb

[image]

Comment: you have relative paths like this everywhere: `<script src="../assets/js/app.min.js"></script>`, use absolute paths instead: `<script src="/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>`. Also, use rails helpers: `javascript_include_tag`, `stylesheet_link_tag`, `image_tag`, etc, don't hardcode the tags, you'll have less headhaches

Comment: OMG... i was looking for that answer 5 years ago. Finally i found a hero.

Comment: @arieljuod do you want to post it final answer? i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have relative paths like this everywhere: `<script src="../assets/js/app.min.js"></script>`, use absolute paths instead: `<script src="/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>`.

Also, use rails helpers like `javascript_include_tag`, `stylesheet_link_tag`, `image_tag`, etc, don't hardcode the tags, you'll have less headhaches.